# Corrplot output format

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am currently trying to fix the visual output of a generated Corrplot but have so far been unsuccessful with two things:

1. The title always gets chopped off the top
2. I can't change the color of the labels from red to black

   ```
   A <- seq(1, 100, by=1)
   B <- sample(A,100, replace =T)
   C <- sample(A,100, replace =T)
   D <- sample(A,100, replace =T)
   E <- sample(A,100, replace =T)
   sample(A,100, replace =T)
   X <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)

   X <- cor(X, method = c("spearman"))

   corrplot(X,
    method = "circle",
    type = "upper",
    diag = F,
    addCoef.col=T,
    title = "Testing")
   ```

Additionally, is it possible to just keep the first 2 variables (i.e A and B) and show the correlation horizontal with every other parameter C-E? Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: im not sure what the last bit means. I can't picture it. For the colour, add `tl.col = 'black'` and for the title one hacky way is to use `title = "\nTesting"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the title from being truncated,  use the `mar` parameter.
To adjust the color of the labels, use the `tl.col` parameter.
To have a horizontal display that only shows (A,B) by (C,D,E),
get rid of  `type="upper"` and `diag=F`,
add `is.corr=F` and then just use the part of the matrix that you want `X[1:2,3:5]`.

Putting that all together, we get

```
corrplot(X[1:2,3:5],
 is.corr=FALSE,
 method = "circle",
 addCoef.col=T,
 mar=c(0,0,5,0),
 tl.col = "black",
 title = "Testing")
```

[image: Adjusted corrplot]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! Is there a way to set the range of values in the right to -20 and 20 for example?

Comment: Try adding `cl.lim=c(-0.2,0.2)`  If you really want -20 to 20  (not -0.2 to 0.2)   multiply X by 100.